# Syncing UILabel with UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to sync two different UILabels with the value from two UITextFields, and if there is no data in the text field, then I would like them to keep their label placeholders that I set in the attributes inspector ("Label 1" & "Label 2"):

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        labelOne.text = labelOneTextField.text
        labelTwo.text = labelTwoTextField.text
}
```

However, when I finish entering text into the first text field and hit Done, the 2nd label becomes blank. So I tried this:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if self.labelOneTextField != nil {
        labelOne.text = "Label 1"
        labelTwo.text = "Label 2"
    } else {  
        labelOne.text = labelOneTextField.text
        labelTwo.text = labelTwoTextField.text
    }
}
```

However, this only sets a rule for if the first text field is blank, and it seems very messy. What is a better way to format this, especially considering that there will be many more text fields/labels in this form. Thank you.

Comment: also, this line: if self.labelOneTextField != nil {  , maybe you should check self.labelOneTextField.text

Answer (score 1):

Just get the value and check it's not empty:

```
if let labelOneText = labelOneTextField.text, !labelOneText.characters.isEmpty {
    labelOne.text = labelOneText
}
if let labelTwoText = labelTwoTextField.text, !labelTwoText.characters.isEmpty {
    labelTwo.text = labelTwoText
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select over the textfields:

```
switch textField {
case labelOneTextField:
    labelOne.text = labelOneTextField.text
case labelTwoTextField:
    labelTwo.text = labelTwoTextField.text
....
default:
    break
}
```